# Was Sam Beckett A Vegetarian?

Tags: quantum-leap

I need to know if Dr. Sam Beckett was a vegetarian or not. Is it possible that he is a vegetarian, but he eats meat while in other people's bodies, just so he doesn't seem strange? I know he made chitlins in one episode, but did he eat it?

Comment: What reason would one have to believe that he was a vegetarian?  Canonically speaking I doubt it is ever addressed, but we can certainly speculate that he was not a vegetarian.  Whenever he lept into a woman's body he didn't suddenly become comfortable wearing womens' clothes, so it is safe to assume that if he was a vegetarian he would not suddenly be okay with eating meat when leaping into the body of an omnivore.

Comment: In theory, it's at least possible that Sam did become a vegetarian sometime before his original leap; however, the "swiss-cheesing" of his memory could have obliterated that. There is certainly some evidence that at least some of the "swiss-cheesing" happens to make it easier for him to perform his on-going "mission"; it would certainly complicate things if he had to explain deciding to be vegetarian in every leap. Still, functionally, we'd only know based on something said by Al (or on the rare occasions they communicate, others from the QL project).

Comment: Did he say he was vegetarian at some point? Perhaps it was an excuse not to eat something in particular, in that case.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not.  In the third episode, "Star-Crossed" Sam meets Donna, a woman who would go on to be the love of his life (although when he leaped, he remembered her as having left him, a few seasons later it's revealed they married, likely as a result of his actions in this episode to help her confront her abandonment issues).

When they meet, he sees a special significance in the fact that Donna, despite not knowing Sam is Sam, knows how he likes his burgers:

> **Sam (VO):** God, how I wanted to tell her I'm not the boozed-out professor she sees, that I was her Sam, the man she'll love 10 years from now, that I'm doing what we dreamed of, I'm traveling in time.
>
> **Donna:** What can I get for you, Dr. Bryant?
>
> **Sam:** Uh, an avion, Evian.
>
> **Donna:** A what?
>
> **Sam:** Uh, C-Coke. Uh, a Coke would be fine.  A Coke, cheeseburger and fries, medium rare on the burger...
>
> **Donna (finishing):** Hold the tomato, extra onion.
>
> **Sam (VO):** She knew. She knew how I liked my burger.  Shove that up your gauge circuit, Ziggy.

Now, although he might pretend to not be a vegetarian, having a specific burger order (and medium rare at that) suggests that he not only enjoys burgers, he enjoys them a certain way.  It's certainly possible that at some point Sam changed to vegetarian for one reason or another and no longer ate burgers willingly, except to "pass" as the original person (and maybe he even legitimately forgot becoming vegetarian, due to the memory issues involved in leaping), but there's no reason to assume it absent evidence to the contrary.